# Using != in \pgfmathparse

Tags: pgfmath

In section *63.1 Operators* of the pgf manual `pgfmanual.pdf` I see the claim that

> x != y returns 1 if x ≠ y, 0 otherwise.

Unfortunately, I can't get that to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathparse{3!=4}
```

gives me a `Missing \begin{document}` error, but replacing `!=` by `<=` works.

Is this a bug in pgfmath, or a misunderstanding on my part? (This may be related to the factorial operator being `!` too.)

Comment: `\pgfmathnotequal{3}{4}` or `\pgfmathparse{notequal(20,25)}` maybe? MATLAB took over the CPU so I can't test :)

Comment: This is "because" your command actually writes `34` to the input, as can be seen by putting it after `\begin{document}`.  Also, it sets `\pgfmathresult = 4`.  This seems like it does not agree with the specification, so I would call it a bug, but as I cannot understand how `pgfmathparse` works, I don't want to glorify that judgment by phrasing it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There seems to be an error in [`pgfmathparser.code.tex`](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex?revision=1.47&view=markup). Line 712 of the latest version (1.47) reads

```
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{!=}{notequalto}{2}{infix} {250}
```

but it should be

```
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{!=}{notequal}{2}{infix} {250}
```

since the function is called `notequal` (not `notequalto`). Changing this line fixes the problem. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Somewhere in the code is written something like `\csname pgf@operator@!=@name\endcsname` which is no doubt applied to the arguments `{3}{4}`.  Since the former expands to `\notequalto`, which does not exist, it turns into `\relax` and the arguments are dumped to the input.  Meanwhile `\pgfmathresult` has been set internally and was not properly reset, so ends up as `4` somehow.

Comment: Fixed in the cvs repository. Thanks for the report and the fix. An updated version of pgf-cvs should become available in the tlcontrib repository in a few days.

Comment: @cjorssen: Wow, that was quick! And so convenient, without even going through the bug tracker! Thanks!